# Automatically get youtube video title when embedding a video in Tumblr

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, tumblr, youtube-javascript-api

Since it is Tumblr I can only use HTML, CSS, and Javascript. PHP is not supported.

---

Answer (score 1):

You should try utilizing the YouTube API.  You can use JavaScript to get the [video details](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries.html) in a JSON response.

Refer: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries.html